# PHP mySQL - Combine Multiple Queries into 1

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my problem:

I have a mySQL database with 3 columns (for simplicities sake - there are other irrelevant columns) and 3000 rows of data (again for simplicities sake), on which I am executing the loop below:

```
$iCount = count($item_ids);
for($i=0;$i<$iCount;$i++){
    $q="SELECT item_id, value_date FROM $dataTable WHERE value_date >= $sDate AND value_date <= $eDate AND price_disc <> 'NA' AND item_id = '".$item_ids[$i]."' ORDER BY value_date";
    $q=$myConn->query($q);
    if($q->num_rows>0){
        $x=0;
        while($row=$q->fetch_assoc()){
            $iData[$i][0]=$row['item_id'];
            $iData[$i][1][$x]=$row['value_date'];
            $x++;
        }
        $q->free();
    }
    set_time_limit(30);
}
```

to fill a PHP array (as you can see).

The above code is working, though VERY slowly as it currently iterates approx 3000 times (one for each item_id).

I am looking for a way to gather the data into an array in the same format as it is currently (with the item_id being array[$i][0] and the value_date being array[$i][1][$x]), but in a single query rather than 3000.

Note: I do not want to have to re-organize the database unless completely necessary.

I am sure there is a simple way to do this.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I know that I can use IN('.join(item_ids).') to make it into one query string, I just don't know how to get the result in an array with the same dimensions as the one I have described.

Comment: can you post how you get item_ids ? if it is from another table use join query, if it is from array using post or something, then just use itemId in (...) and then loop on recordset.

Comment: @MarkBaker running 3000 query will always going to be slow and not recommended for a web page.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table? What does an EXPLAIN return?

Comment: in my opinion you absolutely have to use ezSQL DB Class for into cache for query.

Comment: @SumitGupta: its an array of item_ids(strings), could you post an example of the looping over the record-set using IN(), I was going to try that but am not sure how to keep the price_date(s) linked to their item_id(s) when doing so.

Comment: @IIIOXIII read answer of khms and then example here on how to iterate over recordset : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN`

```
$ids = " ('" . implode(item_ids, "','") . "')" ;

$q ="SELECT item_id, value_date ";
$q.=" FROM $dataTable ";
$q.=" WHERE value_date >= $sDate AND value_date <= $eDate AND price_disc <> 'NA' ";
$q.=" AND item_id IN ".$ids ." ORDER BY value_date";
$stmt=$myConn->query($q);
if($stmt->num_rows>0){
    $x=0;
    $i=0;
    while($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc()){
        $iData[$i][0]=$row['item_id'];
        $iData[$i++][1][$x]=$row['value_date'];
        $x++;
    }
    $stmt->free();
}
```

If your request is still slow, then you have to create an index on your column.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_item_id  ON YOUR_TABLE(item_id);
```

Comment: Could you provide the rest, the code that actually stores the results into the array?  Look at my reply to Sumit Gupta above ^

Comment: @kmas the ideas are in item_ids variable which is an array only, so he can simple implode them to get ids also query is wrong it should have brackets around ids :).

Comment: @IIIOXIII , you've got the rest of the solution in Mauro's post. ;)

Comment: Anyway, now you have discovered the 'IN' operator. The rest is simple.

Comment: @kmas: Yep, plan on creating the index, and was going to use IN with join, the main problem is I just don't know how to get the info output from the single query into an array with the same organization as my example: with each item_id as an array, with an array of corresponding price_dates within it.

Comment: I think it is what you now want.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 3000 queries in a simple page request... too much

Store all your items id's in to an array

```
$stringItemIds = implode(',',$arrayItemsId);

$q="SELECT item_id, value_date FROM $dataTable WHERE value_date >= $sDate AND value_date <= $eDate AND price_disc <> 'NA' AND item_id IN ($stringItemIds) ORDER BY value_date";
```

After that iterate with the query:

```
    $q=$myConn->query($q);
    if($q->num_rows>0){
        $x=0;
        while($row=$q->fetch_assoc()){
            $iData[] = array(
                '0' => $row['item_id'],
                '1' => array('x' => $row['value_date'])
            );
        }
        $q->free();
    }
```

Comment: N.B. `join()` is an alias of `implode()`

Comment: @Mauro: With the above code, in the loop, $i is not changing, $i would need to change in order for the output to be an array of item_id(s) which contain arrays of price_date(s), correct?  That is my delema.

Comment: wasn't advising an edit, just alerting other users in case they wondered what `join()` did. I had to look it up as I had never seen it before but knew of `implode()` :)

Comment: "$i is not changing" - maybe change `$iData[$i][0]=$row['item_id'];` to `$iData[][0]=$row['item_id'];` or if you need the key of `$iData` to be the same use `$iData[key($row)][0]=$row['item_id'];`

Comment: @Mauro: I must be doing something wrong, I keep getting 1 as the result for `count($iData[$i][1])`, `$iData[$i][1]` should be an array of dates for each separate `$iData[$i][0]`.  The dates and their relative item_ids must stay linked.  I want to be able to echo them like: "Here is the item_id: `$iData[$i][0]`" and "Here are the dates relating to that item_id `'$iData[$i][1][0]`,`$iData[$i][1][1]`,`$iData[$i][1][2]`", etc. where `$iData[$i][1]` is an array of the related dates.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Please use my version instead yours. Use $iData[$i][1]['blah']['crazy'] is crazy... could be more easy with $iData[] = array( ... ) ;

Comment: I used your code, however, when i try to check the results by echoing `count($iData[$i][1])`, the results always equal 1, no matter what $i is changed to... `$iData[$i][1]` should be an array of the related dates upon completion of your code should it not?

Comment: my code is exactly the same than yours but without using $i. How are you echoing count($iData[$i][1])? You don't have $i